# Add column to dataframe using multi-index values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is created from external data and roughly looks like this

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([(5, 5821, 5),
                       (5, 5819, 6),
                       (5, 5818, 7),
                       (6, 5818, 12),
                       (7, 119, 20),
                       (7, 118, 0),
                       (7, 116, 11),
                       (7, 115, 15),
                       (7, 114, 17)],
                      columns=(('ID', 'SUBID', 'VALUE'))).set_index(['ID', 'SUBID'])
```

I need a new column `PREV_VALUE`that holds the value of `VALUE`for the current row's `(ID, SUBID - 1)`. That is

```
              VALUE  PREV_VALUE
  ID   SUBID        
   5    5821      5         NaN
        5819      6           7
        5818      7         NaN
   6    5818     12         NaN
   7     119     20           0
         118      0         NaN
         116     11          15
         115     15          17
         114     17         NaN
```

I can muddle my way through using `df['PREV_VALUE'] = df.apply(lambda r: df.VALUE.get((r.name[0], r.name[1]-1), None), axis=1)`, which is horribly slow for large dataframes, though. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.values,
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(tup[0], tup[1]+1)
                                                    for tup in df.index.get_values()],
                                                    names=df.index.names),
                   columns=df.columns)

df.join(df2, how='left', rsuffix='PREV_VALUE')
```

Result:

```
In [126]: df.join(df2, how='left', rsuffix='PREV_VALUE')
Out[126]:
          VALUE  VALUEPREV_VALUE
ID SUBID
5  5821       5              NaN
   5819       6              7.0
   5818       7              NaN
6  5818      12              NaN
7  119       20              0.0
   118        0              NaN
   116       11             15.0
   115       15             17.0
   114       17              NaN
```

Comment: The caveat not clear from my example is that `SUBID` may have holes. That is `SUBID` may be something like "5821, 5820, 5818". The row `5820` needs to be `NaN` because `5819` is missing. With `shift()`, the value of `5818` would get picked up instead.

Comment: @user2722968, could you post a reproducible data set and a desired data set?